# How to calculate heat dissipation of metal box?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

Lets say I have a steel cubical box of size $1$m filled with water at room ($20$°C) temperature. At first everything in box is $20$°C temperature, and then internal water heater (with power of $10$kW) starts heating the water. How to calculate what will be final temperature of whole box? Eventually it should stabilize and achieve some temperature, because those $10$kW will be dissipated into air?

Comment: Well, if you don't include some heat dissipation mechanism in your problem, you get the unphysical solution that the temperature grows with no upper limit. This is simply understood from energy conservation: you have $10$kW of input power and $0$kW of output power, so the internal energy of your system keeps on growing by $10$J per second (and hence temperature rises). In a realistic scenario, many mechanisms of heat dissipation can occur, and eventually there will be a thermodynamic equilibrium, so the dissipated power will be $10$kW as well.

Comment: If the room is perfectly insulated from the outside, the temperature will continue to increase (as well as the room air temperature), and none of the heat will be dissipated.

Comment: What is the mass of the box.The mass of the water?Cp for box and water?

Comment: What is inside the container?Only water or there is some air?This question needs clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively impossible to calculate from first principles. The problem is that the cooling will be dominated by convection i.e. air in the room around the box will flow over the surfaces and cool them. The rate of heat loss will be approximately described by [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling), so the rate of heat loss will be proportional to the temperature difference between the surface of the box and it's environment. However the constant of proportionality will depend on the details of the air flow around the box.

The only practical way to determine the constant of proportionality will be to do the experiment and measure it. Even then you will need to carefully control factors like air flow in and out of the room to get reproducible results.

Comment: I understand. Is there a software (not too difficult to use) so I could simulate it? Maybe Matlab has it?